# Bash compound expression with arithmetic and test

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a compound expression in Bash that uses one expression from arithmetic parentheses `(( ))` and another expression from the test `[ ]`.  This is what I have:

```
if (( ${#INPUT_FILES[@]} > 1 )) -a [ -n "$OUTPUT_FILE" ]; then
```

However I get the error

```
./backup.sh: line 51: syntax error near unexpected token `-a'
./backup.sh: line 51: `if (( ${#INPUT_FILES[@]} > 1 )) -a [ -n "$OUTPUT_FILE" ]; then'
```

`INPUT_FILES` is an array of strings, and `OUTPUT_FILE` is a regular string variable.

How do I logically `and` these two expressions together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-a` flag is a part of the `test` expression syntax itself. Outside the brackets you have to use `&&` and its ilk.

```
if (( ${#INPUT_FILES[@]} > 1 )) && [ -n "$OUTPUT_FILE" ]; then
```

If you have your heart set on using `-a`, you can write it this way:

```
if [ ${#INPUT_FILES[@]} -gt 1 -a -n "$OUTPUT_FILE" ]; then
```

But as Adrian Frühwirth points out in his comment, the `-a` and `-o` flags [are obsolescent in XSI](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), so you should prefer `&&` and `||`.

Comment: +1. On a side note, `-a`/`-o` are de facto deprecated and should not be used due to possible side effects. `&&`/`||` is almost always what you want.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth ah, thanks, I didn't realize. Confirmed and updated.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth thanks, and kojiro thanks for link.  That is good reading.  For future travellers scroll down about half-way to the section called "APPLICATION USAGE" http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html